# How to use JavaScript / JQuery in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to use the inline JavaScript or JavaScript file in MVC. How should I use it in the MVC?

Comment: Why this question needs to be put on hold? I have just added the information question/asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in your `head` section

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC if you are using the Razor view engine then follow the below mentioned steps:

1. Edit the _Layout.cshtml file and move the
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") from footer section to header
   section.
2. Add the code mentioned like below in header section of
   _Layout.cshtml

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var divLength = $('div').length;
        alert(divLength);
    });
</script>
```

If you are using the ASP.Net view engine then you need to edit the Site.Master file and follow the steps sequentially as mentioned in above steps 1 & 2.